# Problem about chance of over $\frac12$ getting their hats out of $10$

Tags: probability

There are $10$ people each with $1$ hat that is indistinguishable. Every person picks up a random hat. What is the probability that over $\frac12$ of the people chooses the wrong hat?

I plan to do principle of inclusion and exclusion, but I'm stuck on how to count the number of cases for each case such as $5$ get their hats and $5$ don't.

This problem is from me, after wanting to attempt something after my problem of $5$ people and $5$ hats. It's inspired by my homework assignment.

My solution (how far I got): We use PIE to count the probability. There are $10!=3628800$ ways to do this. First, we start with at least $5$ hats. This has $120\cdot\binom{10}5$ ways. We have to make a column for each of $5,6,7,8,9,10$ and make sure that each probability is counted once, and only once. Currently, there is in the columns...

Comment: What have you tried? Your try should be written down in the body of the question.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco I tried to use the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion.

Comment: I recommend reading up about Derangements: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Comment: The number of ways of $k$ people getting their own hats and $n-k$ not getting their own hats is $$ \binom{n}{k}\mathcal{D}(n-k) $$ where $\mathcal{D}(k)$ is the number of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of $k$ items.

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Comment: I wrote where it's from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are looking for more than half of the people choose the wrong hat, that means that 4 or fewer people choose the correct hat. If 0 people choose the correct hat, then there are $\dfrac{D_{10}}{10!} = \dfrac{!10}{10!}$.

If 1 person chooses the correct hat, choose the person who chooses the correct hat and multiply by the number of derangements of 9 people: $\dbinom{10}{1}\dfrac{!9}{10!}$

2 ppl choose correctly: $\dbinom{10}{2}\dfrac{!8}{10!}$

3 ppl choose correctly: $\dbinom{10}{3}\dfrac{!7}{10!}$

4 ppl choose correctly: $\dbinom{10}{4}\dfrac{!6}{10!}$

Total probability that at least half of the people choose incorrectly:

$$\dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^4 \dbinom{10}{n}!(10-n)}{10!}$$

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SUM%5BBinomial%5B10,n%5D*Derangement%5B10-n%5D,%7Bn,0,4%7D%5D%2F10!)

Answer (score 2):

Some $k$ people get the wrong hat, with $6\le k\le10$, and the remaining people get the right hat. We can choose the $k$ people in $\binom{10}k$ different ways, and we can assign the wrong hats in $!k$ ways, where $!k$ is the number of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of $k$ objects. Thus the number of these arrangements is

$$
\sum_{k=6}^{10}\binom{10}k!k\;,
$$

and with the numbers from the Wikipedia article, this is

$$
\binom{10}6\cdot265+\binom{10}7\cdot1854+\binom{10}8\cdot14833+\binom{10}9\cdot133496+\binom{10}{10}\cdot1334961=3615536\;.
$$

Comment: Close. You forgot the denominator of $10!.$

Comment: joriki said this is the *number of ways*. The *probability* would be that number divided by the total number of permutations, which is $10!$